# c# finding random number

Tags: c#, random

First of all i am learning c# and i got a homework assignment. But i didn't figure it out myself. I can't find the random numbers. Shall i write it in an apart class or actually i have no idea where i can start.

what i need to do is:

Create a gambling game where the user can bet on a race between two cars . The winner of the
race is determined by the horsepower of the engine of the racing cars . Provide an OO solution
wherein the following classes and their properties are used :

```
car
- number
- Engine
engine
- HP
```

When a car object is created will automatically Engine object created and
are allocated . It is not possible to adjust . The engine of a car Also, the number of PK
of the motor is determined by the creation of the engine and can not be changed by a
external class .
Determining the number of HP in the engine class you can in the following way :

```
<PkProperty> = New Random ( ) Next ( <min> , <max> ) . ;
Example : Pk = new Random ( ) Next (80 , 500 ) .
```

`<PkProperty>` Where the name of your HP property and  and  denote the minimum
and maximum value is between which a random number can be found.
The user will first need to enter the race cars. 2 songs After that, the program
the listing of both cars to = ratio of the probability of winning the 1st car compared to the 2nd car .

Just as the number of PK can be determined with this listing :

```
<notering> = new Random ( ) Next ( <min> , <max> ) . ;
Example : int = new listing Random ( ) Next ( 1 , 30 ) .
```

On the basis of this data, the user must enter the correct number of the car and
the amount he wants to bet . Finally, the program is the result of the race , and any
announce earnings .

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: Bear in mind that English is not the first language of every one !!

Comment: Wow that gave me a headache. I'm guessing a free translator program was used?

Comment: I used "google translate"

Comment: @huMptyduMpty that's completely understandable, but there's a difference between incorrect English grammar and completely incomprehensible sentences.  `The user will first need to enter the race cars. 2 songs After that, the program the listing of both cars to = ratio of the probability of winning the 1st car compared to the 2nd car .`  What does that even mean?!

Comment: Did the code go through the same translator? The syntax of the code is totally wrong.

Comment: @Saggio: Seems we need to bug the google !! :D

Comment: @user2957394 Start by reading your notes from the lessons. Find some books and/or tutorials on programming. Try searching (for example in google) for OOP tutorials. There are (even) lots of examples similar to your problem: [this one - OOP with car example, explanation of class, methods, etc. in C#](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ObjectOrientedConcepts.aspx) and [this one - OOP basics, also with car analogy](http://processing.org/tutorials/objects/). You will probably find something in your native language too. Internet is limitless on resources.

Comment: @user2957394: Your question doesn't point to a specefic problem? this is a full scenario that you put as a question!! As SO mentioned `Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See `[http://SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) `for guidance.`

Comment: allright.seems like nobody is understood :) thanks anyway

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20127984/edit) and put a 2nd copy of your question in your native language at the bottom of your question. People who speak the same language as you and speak English can help fix translation errors.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i didn't translate it myself. I used google translate. but anyway i would like to figure it out myself.

Comment: Google translate made mistakes to make it impossible for us to understand. Please add the original text you put in to Google Translate to the bottom of your question. We still want to help you but we have trouble understanding you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as I understand the question's language the project is pretty simple.
I hope you do not want us to do your homework for you.

1. Create Engine class. Set number and HP fields, set HP property and accessor as read only (only {get;}),.
2. Include constructor that will take no arguments but include Random class instantiator to set HP field. Use Next() twice to ensure randomization.
3. Create Car class, use Engine class as one of its fields, the other car number as int. Set properties for both engine and car number and accessors as get only.
4. Include constructir that will take int as a car number. Hav constructor for car use constructor for engine to instantiate engine.
5. In main class instantiate two cars.
6. Sum the horspower of first and second cars.
7. Create parallel arrays of car numbers and bets and take bets. Also instantiate new Random that you will use in next method.
8. Create Race() method that will take car as an argument and return bool. Use random instantiated in step 7 above to find number between 0 and the sum of both cars' HP. Compare current car's HP to the random number. If number is less or equal to car's HP return true. If not return false.
9. Run method Race() for each car and store result in respective bools. If both bools are true or both are false, it is a draw. If one is true and the other is false - you get a winner.

Comment: thanks. but I didn't get the second one. because we haven't seen that topic yet. I mean the random class.so i did something like  public int Pk
        {
            get
            {
                new Random().Next(number1,number2);

                return pk;
            }